Failed EFI partition resizing
I was not able to install a System Update which require 92MB. On the advice of people in the Framework community, I tried to resize my EFI partition using a live usb of Ubuntu, but now I have unused space in the /boot/efi partition.
My system is a Windows 11 and Unbuntu 24.04 dual boot. The /boot/efi was 100MB and 35MB was used.
Since I didn't really have much installed on the Windows partition, I booted from an Ubuntu live USB, deleted my Windows partition and the Windows recovery partition using "Disks". I couldn't figure out how to resize the /boot/efi partition using "Disks" so I resized it with Gparted to 525MB. It resized the partition but the MB that I added are "unused". Running "Check" in Gparted failed. I downloaded the htm log but I don't know how to view it. Running Check and Repair in Disks worked fine but didn't make the extra MB usable.
Is there a way to repair/check the expanded /boot/efi? I read all the posts about expanding the EFI, but everyone just told the questioner to figure out what was using up all the space in the EFI. In my case, I have only used up 35MB of space, so I think I actually do need a bigger EFI partition in order to install the System Update.


enter image description here

Can you add a screenshot of Gparted to your question?

Are you trying to fix a Windows install? Don't use Linux tools.

No, I am not trying to fix a Windows install. I am trying to do a Laptop 13 AMD Ryzen 7040 System Update in Ubuntu. I deleted the windows partition b/c it was next to the /boot/efi partition, so that was the only way I figured I could expand the EFI partition.

I had the same problem with my new laptop running Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 dual boot as well; a firmware upgrade could not be installed due to complains about EFI size(100MB as well, default value with the Windows 11 installer). As someone mentioned, Linux-based partitioners as gparted or kde partition manager won't let you to fix it, or at least, in my case it was impossible; nevertheless Win 11 installer partitioner works for that.
So instead, the solution that worked for me was, after backing up the important data, erasing all partitions, followed by a fresh install of Win 11. In the step of partitions, create a big partition for the EFI, do not let the default 100MB for it; the partitioner is a bit tricky, but it is possible. Then, follow the Win 11 install as usual, install your Ubuntu or whatever as you did before, mounting the /boot/efi on that bigger-than-100MB ESP you created during the Win 11 install. Since I did that, I could install everything related to EFI without the system complaining, as it has now space.
Many people would say I am wasting disk space, and yes, perhaps 500MB or even 400 or 300MB for the ESP could be enough, but I gave it 2GB, because at the moment I have multiboot with Win 11 and other 3 OS and nobody knows if in the next years firmware upgrades become bigger, but I don't want to be exposed to that. 2GB is nothing compared with my 1TB or your 4TB, so go ahead.
Good luck if you give it a try!
